# How to change transparency of last few characters on a trimmed string

Tags: css

Here is the problem:

- I have a list of items with various length for then name.
- I want to trim the names to 140 pixels if they are longer.
- As a nice clean way
  of demonstrating to users that the string is trimmed, I want to
  reduce transparency of the last few characters of the name, or at
  least create that illusion.
- I do **not** want to use the ellipsis... effect for several good reasons.

I this possible in pure CSS?

Comment: 140 pixels or 140 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure can, using CSS. You have two options, but really only the first will get the best results cross-browser.

The idea is to overlay a pseudo-element over the right of your element containing the string. This will only work if it's on a solid background color, as we will use that color to "fade" to.

HTML

```
<span>This string ends with an gradient to the background color overlayed</span>
```

CSS

```
span {position:relative;}
span.overlay:after {
    content:"\0020";
    display:block; width:50px; 
    position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px; z-index:2;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    background-image:linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    /* Or use an actual png image fading to white for IE < 10 support */
}
```

the `:after` element will work in all browsers, IE8+. The `-ms-gradient` only in IE10+, so either figure out how to use the old ie gradient filters, or use a PNG image.

There's also another newer CSS method, but  *currently only supported by webkit (Chrome & Safari),* `mask-image`. Here, you can use an image or a CSS gradient to mask an element. Same principal, except you can actually fade the element (in the case your text was on a patter).

```
span{
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0px, rgba(0,0,0,1) 50px);
}
```

You can check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/b96sv/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this but you must wrap each of the trailing characters in a `<SPAN>` and set the CSS opacity for each.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but as I said I was looking for a pure CSS solution so I didnt have to put in the logic to figure out the characters needing to be transparent.